# Disabling in app notification but keeping notifications in the notification centre

Tags: android, kotlin, urbanairship.com

I use airship for push notifications and wondering if it is possible to disable in app notifications while keep notifications in the centre.

I have tried
       `UAirship.shared().privacyManager.disable(PrivacyManager.FEATURE_IN_APP_AUTOMATION)`

but it does not seem to work. Could anyone share their insights on this?

Thank you for your help